# [dotnet core MVC], I can't get file from byte array (field stored into database).

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm becoming crazy to get physical file from database field. I use asp.net MVC project (dotnet core 1.1). Thanks in avance and happy Christams!

> **In some part of my CONTROLLER :**

```cs
public void Download(int id)
{
    downloadMyFile(_context.myTable.Find(id).MyBLOBField,
                _context.myTable.Find(id).MyFieldContentType, 
                _context.Richieste.Find(id).MyFieldOriginalFileName
     );
 }

public FileContentResult downloadMyFile(byte[] fileBytes, 
                                  string fileContent, string fileName)
{
            return File(fileBytes, fileContent, fileName);
}
```

> **My VIEW :**

```
<a asp-action="Download" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"> Download File</a>
```

**

> **My notes:**

If I use this, works:

```
public FileResult download()
        {
            var fileName = @"myRealFileNameStoredInTheServer.ext";
            var filepath = $"Downloads/{fileName}";
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
            return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", fileName);
        }
```

**BUT WHEN PASS BYTE ARRAY FROM ANOTHER BYTE ARRAY DOESN'T WORK**

I'm try also using Response method, but I can't find BinaryWrite() on the ASPNET CORE overloads of Response... nothing also using a MemoryStream! **Can you help me please..?**

Comment: Your method is `void` - it does not return anything

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: Make it `public FileContentResult Download(int id)` (and make the other method `private`) so it returns the result of `downloadMyFile()` - `return downloadMyFile(.....);`

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. explain "doesn't work" (exception, nothing happens, which line in source, ...), elaborate on the "byte array from another byte array" part and consider removing the part before "If I use this, works", as it seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks solved. I I did not regard the first call from a VOID method

Answer (score 0):

> Read the comment of  Stephen Muecke for understand what has been my
>   issue.

```
 public FileContentResult Download(int id)
 {
    return File(_context.myTable.Find(id).MyBLOBField,
                _context.myTable.Find(id).MyFieldContentType, 
                _context.Richieste.Find(id).MyFieldOriginalFileName
     );
 }
```